# How to find site’s JSON APIs/URLs?

Tags: json, rest, api, http

I remember coming across APIs/URLs like: `http://www.testsite.com/students.json`, which returns a JSON response, and read somewhere that you can find it via e.g. Chrome dev tool under Network tab.

Where/how can I find the JSON APIs/URLs? Would ultimately use `requests` to fetch the JSON.

Comment: Yes, it's in the network tab, but the URL doesn't need to end with .json

Comment: Not every developer follows API centric approach or want to expose api to others.

Comment: Some websites do not have a JSON based API and use server-generated  HTML pages for users. Which is the case with skateboard shop you mentioned.

Comment: If you still want to dig further.. you might want to scrape the page for links and stuff. Checkout `beautifulsoup`.

Comment: @cricket_007 But if I do want to discover any APIs that the site uses, I would do it via Chrome dev tool, under Network tab, correct?

Comment: @jitendra If I want to find out any APIs, the only place I can do it is via Chrome dev tool, under Network tab?

Comment: @Vasif Appreciate the response! But thought working with APIs would be faster. The only other faster alternative would be `beautifulSoup`? Aware of that web scraping but just thought it is slow.

Comment: Based on the fact that the HTML has `<div id="product-loop"`, then I am going to guess the site uses server-side HTML rendering, which does not require JSON to be used or exposed. Not every site needs/uses a REST endpoint

Comment: I tried to answer with a  prose to explaining some concepts. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The best place to find out about a JSON-based API is the documentation provided by API's maintainer. Typically, maintainers who would like their API to be consumed by clients provide documentation. Sometimes, they build a navigable API where responses have http links to other resources of their API and do not provide an explicit documentation. If they do so, that could be called as implicit documentation.

Networks tab in a web browser's developers' tools provides a way to capture network traffic going in and out of the browser. If a website makes any asynchronous http request, that will be captured and shown here. Again depending on the design and strategy of the website maker, this could be a JSON based response coming from a URL or a HTML or any other type. `Content-Type` header hints at the type of response. You can use this cue as well to see if the content of the response is `application/json`. Thus, obtaaining a url that you can use in your scripts.

What you are trying to do here is observing a website's network traffic from your browser and are trying to see if there is any link that brings you a JSON based response instead of HTML. So, that you can use a JSON parser instead of a HTML parser. Possibly, because HTML parsers are slow.

The Answer to your specific question is, if you get lucky you might find a  link that serves a JSON response. If not, you might wanna fall back on HTML parsing.